# Is uCLinux support ARM Cortex M0?

Tags: arm, linux, cortex-m0

I just do some Google Search about this and it just shows me something like uCLinux on Cortex M3,4. Is it possible to run uCLinux on ARM Cortex M0? (And how? Please give me some reference for that.)

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M), Cortex M0 is based on *ARMv6-M architecture* only support most Thumb 1 and some Thumb 2, while M3 support all Thumb1 and Thumb2 with more instruction, so is that makes the difference?

Also, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CClinux) said that uCLinux only supports M3, M4 and M7 but not M0.

Comment: @EugeneSh I edited the post and there is no longer that question :) Now I think it's stupid since I ask for a general M0 but not a specific one.

Comment: You’d be wanting a few megabytes of ram methinks. You could comfortably run Unix on the M0 with only a couple of hundred kbytes. Not sure why you’d want to, but I did it for kicks.

Comment: *You could comfortably run Unix on the M0 with only a couple of hundred kbytes* - So you *did* run it? And how?

Comment: I don't remember any Cortex-M0 with an *external* memory interface, so you cannot put enough RAM in the system to run uCLinux.
Note that I may missed the oddball M0 with external memory somewhere, but it seems to be rare at least.

Comment: There does not seem to be Cortex-M0 support officially, as you have already figured out. The project also seem to not be very actively maintained, last update is going back to 2018, so perhaps you better look at alternatives.

Comment: Pdp11 emulation with a serial psram and flash for disk storage. Runs a real release of Unix. I should try it on a raspi pico to see how fast it is. As for running uclinux on a M0, you’d be making a rod for your back considering there are many more viable alternatives using ‘normal’ linux.